# Файл манифеста и определение версии Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

Подскажите пожалуйста или дополните мои действия:

-Есть либа, которая некорректно определяет версию Windows.

-Советуют добавить некий манифест для корректности работы WinApi`шных функи по определению версии Windows. Как я понимаю это вот это: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1

-Открываю пустой блокнот - вставляю туда текст этого манифеста и сохраняю, как - "compatibility.manifest"

-Далее открываю VS2019 --> Инструменты манифеста ---> полe: Дополнительные файлы манифеста: указываю полный путь к файлу: C:\my_folder\compatibility.manifest

Компилирую --> все компилируется --> запускается --> и версия Windows так же коряво определяется.
Причем все это происходит только в дебаг версии, в release версии никакого манифеста не требуется и без него все корректно определяется.

Что я делаю не так ? Или что я пропустил ?

Comment: *"все это происходит только в дебаг версии"* - ну значит 4 пункт не был выполнен для дебаг версии. *"Или что я пропустил ?"* - необходимость предоставлять [mcve] в подкрепление подобных заявлений

Comment: @user7860670, я это естественно делал, только в свойствах для debug версии. Я бы представил минимальный воспроизводимый пример, но не понимаю, как это сделать в данной случае.

Comment: Сделайте библиотеку с одной функцией, определяющей версию. Сделайте исполняемый файл, дергающий эту функцию. Проверьте поведение в зависимости от наличия / отсутствия манифеста.

Comment: @user7860670, поведение одинаковое в этом и дело :(